# String comparison of two urls fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a pretty simple string comparison, but the check always fails. I'm trying to load different images loaded in an `<img>` based on the `window` width.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    console.log(width);
    $('.slider-image').each(function() {
        resize_image( $(this), width );
    });
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    $('.slider-image').each(function() {
        resize_image( $(this), width );
    });
});

function resize_image( image, width ) {
    console.log(width);
    if( width >= 480 && width < 768 ) {
        if(image.attr( 'src' ) != image.data( 'phone-src' ) ); {
            console.log( 'resize phone' );
            image.attr( 'src', image.data( 'phone-src' ) );
        }
    } else if ( width >= 768 && width < 960 ) {
        if(image.attr( 'src' ) != image.data( 'tablet-src' ) ); {
            console.log( 'resize tablet' );
            image.attr( 'src', image.data( 'tablet-src' ) );
        }
    } else if ( width >= 960 ) {
        if(image.attr( 'src' ) != image.data( 'desktop-src' ) ); {
            console.log( 'resize desktop' );
            image.attr( 'src', image.data( 'desktop-src' ) );
        }
    }
};
```

Now, what I want to happen is, `don't replace the src, if the width remains within the borders`. I'm trying to do this by checking if the `src` attribute already has that `data` attribute, but the string check for it fails as it always not equal, although both attributes are the same in Chrome Inspector. Why does this happen?

By the way, both strings are URLs of images.

Comment: What does `console.log(image.attr( 'src' ), image.data( 'phone-src' ))` print?

Comment: Add some labelled debug statements before each comparison, e.g.
console.log('debug1', image.attr( 'src' ), image.data( 'phone-src' ) );
This way you can check which 'if' branch executes, and what values you are comparing.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario the 'src' prints a clickable link, and the `data` prints a non clickable link. Other than that, it's the same URL.

Comment: If it's clickable, it's probably an object rather than a string.

Comment: When I log them seperately, they are both clickable links though. But the URLs are exactly the same. If I copy paste them and put them in strings and compare them, the check works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had a sneaky semi-colon behind every if statement... Removed those and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Why the extra parentheses after your console logs?

```
console.log( 'resize phone' ));
```

I checked comparing `src` and `data` attrs, and they match. Unless your images are not tagged with `data-phone-src=""` etc, I'm thinking that line is preventing setting the src.

Answer (score 0):

You might check if the src is a string primitive or String().

```
new String("hi") == new String("hi");  // false
```

Comment: sorry, updated my answer, since I misunderstood the question initially.